# How to insert data into specific row without hardcode

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

The aim of this code is to achieve the following:

-Enter username

-Check if exists on DB

-If not create new user

-Add currency & balance to new user row

The issue is with my insert statement. I'm not sure how to use the WHERE condition while inserting data using defined variables. Help would be welcomed!

Error Message: TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (4 given)

```
def add_user():strong text
  print("enter new username")
  UserLogin = str(input())
  c.execute("SELECT username FROM FinanceDBTable")
  enter code here
  for row in c.fetchall():
    print()

#Convers tuple to string without spaces
    UserNameDB = ''.join(row)

    if UserNameDB == UserLogin:
                print('This username already exisits. please try again')
                add_user()
    else:
            print("Please enter your balanace\n")
            userbalance = input()
            print("Please enter currency\n")
            userCurrency = input()
            c.execute("INSERT INTO FinanceDBTable (balance, currency) VALUES (?,?)",
            (userbalance, userCurrency), "WHERE (username) VALUES (?)", (UserLogin))
            conn.commit()
```

Comment: I think your insert statement needs to be a single string with a single (3-element) tuple as the only other argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to do this, also does not use recursion which is seen as unpythonic and also will eventually throw errors. Plus made it a bit more pythonic.
I'm not sure if you can use WHERE in INSERT statements, you can in UPDATE maybe that where you're getting that idea from, but by also giving the username value with the other will work for what you are trying to achieve i think.

```
def add_user():
    while True:
        username = input("Username: ")
        c.execute("SELECT username FROM FinanceDBTable WHERE username = ?", (username,))
        results = c.fetchall()
        if len(results) < 1:
            # Add user as there is not user with that username.
            user_balance = int(input("Please enter your balance: "))
            user_currency = input("Please enter currency: ")
            c.execute("INSERT INTO FinanceDBTable(username, balance, currency) VALUES (?,?,?)", (username, user_balance, user_currency))
            conn.commit()
            break
        else:
            # User already exists
            print('This username already exists, please try again.')
```